# Learning ASP.NET in a structured way

Tags: asp.net

I have been a developer in ASP.NET for a few years now. My learning has been sparadic so i feel my knowledge is a bit patchy. I normally search how i can fix a problem and solve it but I want to have a better overall understanding in a structured way so I can be a better coder.

Can I get some suggestions on websites/books or similar that would be able to assist with making me a better coder?

I learn by doing so having tasks along the way would help.

As above

Answer (score 0):

My way:

1. learn C#: track language changes in new releases, read reddit
   topics about language
2. learn .net core: msdn blogs and reddit topics
3. learn architecture patterns and explore other companies expirience with disrupted and scalable 
   systems: reddit, medium, meetups, conferences(if you can't attend events, usually there are translations or videos from there)
4. track news and blogposts about related areas - big data, docker, microservices, databases, etc: reddit, medium
5. Read books often - you can find list of books for programmer easily in internet using google. As for me must have minimum : Domain-driven design(Eric Evans), Refactoring(Beck), Clean code(Martin), Design Patterns(band of four), java concurrency in practise(yes, it's about java, but more important it's about concurrency)

Comment: Pretty sure this is what OP has been doing and they want to take an organized approach at relearning things.

Comment: aspnet core "Get started"(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows) is enough to do web apps using net core, but after that there are a lot of things that not language specific - architecture, storages, load blancing, app scaling, microservices and many others

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2 by Adam Freeman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/148423149X). This book provides the structured way to learn ASP.NET Core MVC, and does so by letting you dive straight into the coding and hands-on practice.
I knew nothing about ASP.NET Core MVC, and when I finished this book in 18 days, I was capable enough to develop middle level ASP.NET Core projects on my own. I request you to give it a try.